# Can PowerCenter write directly to a JSON target?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I know Informatica Cloud has a JSON target connector and I know you can build a JSON source in B2B DT Studio for PowerCenter, but don't see in the version 9.0 documentation that PowerCenter can write directly to a JSON target.  Is it a feature in later or future releases of PowerCenter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a JSON Connector available in Informatica Marketplace. You can avail the 30 day trail of that plug-in and can check whether it works for you or not. These functionalities are provided by this connector:
•Create, update, and merge new JSON files.
•Load data into JSON arrays.
But to use this you need subscription to Informatica Cloud Integration Edition.
Please go to this link for further information: [Informatica JSON Connector Link](https://community.informatica.com/solutions/cloud_json_connector)

Comment: What about a PowerExchange connector for JSON for an on-premises installation of PowerCenter?

Comment: Yes that is also an option if you know how to work with PWX data maps.